# why Chinese pronounce 'θ' to 's'

Tags: pronunciation, th

Such as `python`'s pronunciation, many Chinese pronounce to **`[p’ɑɪsən]`** but neither `[p’ɑɪθɑn]` or `[p’ɑɪθən]`.

Why? Is there any reason or historical about?

And how could I correct them?

Comment: Can i perceive `ð` similar to `θ` in my answer?

Comment: Of course, learning it, THX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simply that in each language, these sounds are perceived to be closer to the English sounds than other sounds available in their inventory:

- /θ/ /ð/ are dental fricatives
- [s] [z] (the common mandarin realisations) are alveolar fricatives, so that which is different is the place of articulation

[image]

> A particular sound which does not exist in the native language can therefore pose a difficulty for the second language learners to produce or some times to try to substitute those sounds with similar ones in their mother tongue. These sounds include both vowels and consonants. For example, there are no vowels like /æ/, /au/, and /ɛə/, etc. or no such consonants as /ð/, /θ/. Therefore learners have trouble first of all in perceiving these sounds, and consequently try to find nearest equivalents to substitute those new sounds. A typical example will be the substitution of /s/ or /z/ for the English /ð/, /ai/ or /e/ for the English /æ/ as in the word ‘that’.
>
> - [A Study of Pronunciation Problems of English Learners in China](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4732/7dad6066a0a6aa1e37a83b5ac8a5d236a583.pdf)

More simply put, speakers of languages that do not have [θ] misperceive this sound differently, and it depends on their native language. Additionally, if the person has never heard the *supposed* pronunciation of `θ` in their native language/other language, then they can easily mispronounce it.

Explanations taken from linguistics.SE [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28598/why-is-the-english-phoneme-%CE%B8-pronounced-like-t-in-indian-accents-but-s-in/)

Comment: Also, to be fair, this goes both ways - Chinese has some consonant sounds that English doesn't have, either, like the sound represented by "q" in romanisations of Chinese words.